# How to use echo result in form

Tags: php, mysql, echo

This is my code which echos result from a database where $tier_two and $drop are variables which have been set from a drop down menu.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM two_drops WHERE tier_two='$tier_two' AND tier_one='$drop'") 
    or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {
              $var='<br><a href="link.php">'.$row['name'].'</a>';
              echo $var;

            }
```

I want to use the echo'd out result in a contact form so that it fills the first form area.
if the  echo result is james.
CONTACT FORM:
name is james
surname is ....
city is......
How can i do this?

Comment: Don't echo it there. Save the data to an array then output the fields in the form when/where you want them.

Comment: Like @chris85 said - save them to variables and echo them where ever you want. If you want to echo in input field, echo it to the value attribute of the field. By the way - you code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @chris85 how do i save the data to an array? i am a total newbie. sorry

Comment: I'm not even sure he has to save it.... blame the question, it's very vague.

Comment: Change `$var=` to `$var[]=`. Then loop through `$var` later when you are building the form. Links: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php